# jquery textarea editors with spell check

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery textarea editors with spell check  . any editors ? or any any spell check plugins which does inline spell check, while typing itself.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has an interface to spellChecker.net. There's a demo [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo).

It's not jQuery based but works fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

> or any any spell check plugins which
>   does inline spell check, while typing
>   itself.?

Have a look at:

- [jQuery Spell Check Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellcheck)

Comment: You can find the updated version here: https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker

Answer (score 1):

Here's a new one with good jQuery integration.  It has a full jQuery dialog, with undo functions, etc.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jspeller

Answer (score 1):

Though an old question yet http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com looks promising.

**Edited**

Here is the link which has a demo of inline spell check as we type
http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_Spell_As_You_Type_Demo

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Taifun, sorry. I am updating now.